# Failed to send an email using php

Tags: php, html, email, heroku

I'm trying to make my form work so I can receive emails. My website is currently stored on Heroku and everything looks fine, except it doesn't send emails after the form is submitted. Can someone help me please?

index.php :

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="email.php">
    <input class="holder" placeholder="Name" type="text" name="name" required>
    <input class="holder" placeholder="Email" type="email" name="email" required>
    <textarea class="holder" placeholder="Drop me some lines" type="text" name="message"></textarea>
    <div class="button-position">
        <button id="button-submit" type="submit"><p id='submit_word'>Submit</p><img class="send-spaceship" src="resources/css/images/send-spaceship.png"></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

email.php:

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];


    $email_from = "itzikshaoulian@gmail.com";

    $email_subject = "Form Submission";

    $email_body = "User Name: $name.\n".
                    "User Email: $visitor_email.\n".
                        "User Message: $message.\n";


    $to = "itzikshaoulian@gmail.com";

    $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

    $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

    header("Location: https://itzikshaoulianportfolio.herokuapp.com/");
?>
```

Comment: Also, be sure to sanitize `$visitor_email`, and verify there are no new lines present. Hackers can add on other headers, and basically hijack your mail function.

Comment: Heroku doesn't support native outbound email. I recommend using the Mailgun API.